# dir-color failure in html and css files in several terminals

Tags: colors

I use several types of terminals in my Slackware 13 distribution: xterm, rxvt, Konsole, and xfce's terminal emulator (Terminal 0.4.6). All of them read my .dir_colors file and, for the most part assign colors to file-types as I wish. The exception are html files and css files, (e.g. blah.html and blee.css).

The rxvt terminal has no problems, but none of the other terminals will colorize these files properly. The terminal emulator displays:  `[00:33mblee.css`, (the first character looks like a small 2x2 array of 1's and 0's in a box. The above is cut-and-paste from the terminal.). Konsole displays: `33mblah.html`. xterm doesn't even try to colorize html and css files, but leaves them white (default text color).

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the color entries have gotten entered incorrectly. Pass them through `od -c` in order to see what they are and how they need to be corrected.

Comment: thanks for introducing me to od. I hadn't played with it before. I'm not sure it helped, tho. Here's the run:

Comment: thanks for introducing me to od. I hadn't played with it before. I'm not sure it helped, tho (the file being looked at is blah.css which contains: .blah { font-size: 9pt;} ) -- $> od -c blah.css. Here's the result:                                                   0000000 \n . b l a h  { \n  f o n                                                  0000020   t  - s i z e :  9 p t ; \n  }                                                        0000036

Comment: On the color entries, not the files.

Comment: what now? Sorry to be obtuse. I've looked at the man page of od, and done a little research on the net, but don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Examine `.dir_colors`.

Comment: gracias amigo. problem is fixed.